# Solve inverse problems of the form y=Ax-b?

Tags: python, module, package, sparse-matrix, matrix-inverse

Are there any packages or modules to solve an inverse problem of the form y=Ax-b, where y are the measurements, A the known design matrix, x the unknown parameter and b the known truncation errors? I searched a lot, but I found only solutions for the form y=Ax, e.g. like in linvpy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,
you can for example use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
np.linalg.solve(A, y+b)
```

This works because y=Ax-b is equivalent to y+b=Ax

Comment: All I can say about that is that it is an embarrassment for me :D Thank you really much for that hint.